# Using both @objc and @IBDesignable

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to use a swift library I found on github in my objective-c project. I've followed the instructions here: [How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

And the answer tells me that

```
"To be accessible and usable in Objective-C, a Swift class
must be a descendant of an Objective-C class or it must be marked @objc."
```

But in the swift library source code there is already @IBDesignable prepended to the class

```
@IBDesignable public class ClassName: UIControl {
```

Would I be allowed to add @objc after @IBDesignable like this?

```
@IBDesignable @objc public class ClassName: UIControl {
```

Because when I run my app the app crashes and the only thing logged is

```
 lldb
```

when I try to instantiate the swift class in my objective-c code

```
ClassName *color = [[ClassName alloc] init];
```

And here is how I import the library

```
#import "ClassName-swift.h"
```

So I don't know if the app is crashing because I'm not allowed to append @objc after @IBDesignable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `@objc` tag because `UIControl` is an Objective-C class.